# Зависимость ширины пирамиды, от её высоты(ограничение вложенного цикла)

Tags: java, массивы

Поделитесь пожалуйста своим мнением, что означает кусок кода "j > h - 2 - i && j < h + i". Понимаю, что это зависимость ширины пирамиды, от её высоты, но более подробно пожалуйста. P.S. Данный метод рисует пирамиду из символов "^".

```
public String piramid(int h) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < h * 2 - 1; j++) {
                builder.append((j > h - 2 - i && j < h + i) ? "^" : " ");
            }
            if (i < h - 1) {
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
    }
        return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Навскидку можно выделить следующие расчеты:

Фактически в решении задачи строится два треугольника с общей высотой. Это возможно увидеть, составив соотношение высоты и основания:

h = 1, осн. = 1

h = 2, осн. = 3

h = 3, осн. = 5

h = 4, осн. = 7

Для этого возможно вывести формулу соотношения высоты к основанию: (h*2 - 1 = осн). Если взять отдельный треугольник, у нас получается задача заливки половины квадрата с ребром h по диагонали.

Само условие проверки можно разбить на две части:

1) (j > h - 2 - i) При соответствии условия закрашивается прямоугольный треугольник, где первый катет = h, а второй h-1, для того чтоб не было задвоения катета со вторым треугольником.

2) (j < h + i) При соответствии условия закрашивается прямоугольный равносторонний треугольник, где стороны равны h

В первой части вместо (- 1) используется (-2) т.к. отсчет координат происходит с 0 а не 1

Более простое решение можно предоставить в виде кода:

```
 public String piramid(int h) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (int x = 1; x < h * 2; x++) {
            builder.append((x < h - y || x > y + h) ? " " : "^");
        }
        if (y < h - 1)
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```